# Cloudflare Polish - serve webp/avif images without using /cdn-cgi/image/ URL prefix

Tags: cloudflare

Under the [documentation for Cloudflare Polish](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/polish/) it is mentioned about using the `format=auto` option. Is there a way to use this option without using the `/cdn-cgi/image/` path prefix in my image URLs?

If I do use that path then I see the images served with the `content-type: image/webp` response header. Without the special URL, I don't see any change to the content-typem (it's just served as jpeg).

The documentation

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to route images via /cdn-cgi/ to make use of Cloudflare Polish.
This is applied automatically to images with no change needed to be applied on the URLs.

If you are troubleshooting any issues with this

1. clear the cloudflare cache for the image URL(s) in question
2. check the `cf-polished` response header on the image as this will tell you if optimisation has taken place or if the image was already optimised and thus webp does not give any benefits (in which case you would see the `status=webp_bigger` in the cf-polished header).